# Importing delimited files into SQL server

Tags: sql-server, import

I am trying to import a large file into SQL server that is | delimited.

I know basically nothing about the data, I just want to get it imported.

When I go to Database->tasks->import I use the advanced option to suggest types, and provide padding.

The problem is that that routine does not go through the whole file, even when I specify an absurly large number of rows (1000000000), and so I am constantly getting tructation->error, change the types, restart the import etc errors.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Note:** The file is not on the same machine as SQL Server

Comment: Please check the datatype in your table. Is it exactly matching with your source filed?

Answer (score 6):

I would use Bulk insert.  If you have a delimited file, it should be pretty easy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

A sample looks like this

```
BULK INSERT dbo.MyTable
   FROM 'c:\test\test.txt'
   WITH 
      (
         FIELDTERMINATOR ='|',
         ROWTERMINATOR =' \n'
      );
```

### EDIT:

Based on the given requirements (the file cannot be copied, and a share cannot be used), My recommendation would be to develop your own SSIS package.  In the package you will be able to choose your source and play with the data types.  The suggest types seems to be a constant miss when I have used it, so I wouldn't rely on that.  I would look at a row of the data in Excel and determine, what data type and how large you should make it.  Sorry there is no silver bullet here.

Note: You can go through the import wizard and save the package, if you want to start from that point, instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: This does not work as the file is not on the same machine as the server (see note)

Comment: Can you copy the file to the database server, or put the file on a share that the database server can see?

Comment: No, it is not allowed

Comment: @soandos how do you want to load it into the SQL Server if the db server doesn't have access to the file? Please read Adam's question again.

Comment: @Marian if I right click on the database, there is a task->import file option. I am using the procedure that adam suggests, except that I am looking for a "silver bullet"

Comment: The silver bullet is going to be the BULK INSERT command, but in order for this to work the SQL Server Service account has to be able to see the file (if you are using SQL Authentication) or you will have to perms the file (Windows Authentication)... What I am confused about is how you can see the file from the import wizard, but not from Bulk insert, if the file is not on the db server and not on a files share.

Comment: @soandos please change Adam's text by using a network share format for the file name, eg: \\server\folder\file.csv. Use the same file path that you use in the Import task. Let's see from there if there are permission issues.

Comment: Do you have security delegation (Kerberos) set up for your landscape? If you are running the wizard from your desktop, it is going directly after the file.  If you run BULK INSERT from your desktop it hops to the server, then hops again to the file location.  This could be the double-hop problem. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx

Comment: @AdamHaines The file is on a local machine, not a network share. The import wizard is from SQL management studio, not sql server